"no platform load command" warning
What does this warning message indicate & how can I provide the correct "platform load command"?
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/..../sdgr/..../ftnmmct.f.52.o', assuming: macOS

I seem to only get this when linking objects built by ifort. I'm on MacOS 14.4, which is not an Intel machine... But still I'd like to know how to suppress or resolve these linker warnings while I test various supported fortran compilers.

Which release of oneAPI is this? Where does the file ftnmmct.f come from? Is it a file you are compiling or did the compiler take it from somewhere? Does something similar happen for ifx, icc and icx?
